# Becoming root from inside Vim

Tags: vim, sudo, root

Sometimes I start editing configuration files in `/etc` using Vim, but forget to use `sudo` to start Vim. The inevitable result then is that after finishing my edits I encounter the dreaded notice that I don't have the permission to save the file.

Mostly the edits are small enough that I just exit Vim and do the whole thing again as root. I could of course save to a location I can write to and then copy as root, but that is also somewhat annoying.

But I'm sure there is an easier way to become root or use `sudo` from inside Vim, without having to discard the changes. If the method would not rely on `sudo` being set up for the user that would be even better.

Comment: I got into the habit of using `sudoedit` instead of `vim` for all admin editing.  It's one way to never run into this problem anymore :).  +1 for [Gilles' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11009/9537).

Comment: These alernative Q&A's from SO are useful so linking to them here: [Getting root permissions on a file inside of vi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005/getting-root-permissions-on-a-file-inside-of-vi) & [How does the vim “write with sudo” trick work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

sudo cannot change the effective user of an existing process, it always creates a new process that has the elevated privileges and the original shell is unaffected. This is a fundamental of UNIX design. I most often just save the file to /tmp as a workaround. If you really want to save it directly you might try using a feature of Vim where it can pipe a file to another process. Try saving with this command:

```
:w !sudo dd of=%
```

Tested and works.  Vim will then ask you to reload the file, but it's unnecessary: you can just press <kbd>o</kbd> to avoid reloading and losing your undo history.  You can even save this to a Vim command/function or even bind it to a key for easy access, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: You should wrap the `%` in quotes in case the filename contains a space.

Comment: Also: this will not reset the `'modified'` setting; you can do that manually with `set nomodified`.

Comment: Actually, if you really want to be careful, you should do `exec 'w !sudo dd of=' . shellescape(expand('%'))` in case the filename contains quotes, backslashes, dollar-signs, etc.

Comment: How is that different to the Commandlinefu -command by plaes?

Comment: @hhh Using tee as @plaes suggests will send the entire file to your terminal screen as well as write it out to the filesystem which may not be very desirable, especially when editing a large file over a slow terminal/network connection.

Comment: One could always add `> /dev/null` to the `tee` command.

Comment: Hmm, maybe someone needs to post the performance comparison between using "dd of=%" vs. "tee % >/dev/null"  On one hand dd copies using tiny 512 byte blocks, but on the other hand, tee spins it's wheels writing a full copy of the file to the bit-bucket.  I wonder who will win in the end.

Comment: this throws an error for me: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`. `askpass` is accessible directly and works fine normally.

Answer (score 41):

Saving the file as root:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

Answer (score 14):

Call `sudoedit` to edit files as root.

Think of the inconvenience when calling `vim` directly as a warning that you're being too casual in doing something potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 8):

You can put this in your `.vimrc`

```
cmap w!! %!sudo tee > /dev/null %
```

You trigger it by doing `:w!!` - it will push the file through `sudo tee` to the current filename (`%`).

From a now-deleted post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95072/what-are-your-favorite-vim-tricks; see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim

Comment: And if you've got moreutils installed, just use `!sudo sponge %` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This also works well:

```
:w !sudo sh -c "cat > %"
```

This is inspired by the comment of @Nathan Long in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work).

**NOTICE**:

`"` must be used instead of `'` because we want `%` to be expanded before passing to shell.