# How to get root inside of vi?

Tags: sudo, root, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Becoming root from inside Vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/becoming-root-from-inside-vim)

It could happen to anyone. The admin types:

```
vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

as a regular user. He edits the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, but when he wants to hit `:x` he suddenly notices that he was editing the file in read-only mode because he opened it with a normal user, not root.

Are there any vi commands to get root privileges, so that the admin won't have to hit `:q!` and `sudo su -` and `vi /etc/resolv.conf` and edit it again?

Comment: OT, but `sudo vi /etc/resolve.conf` should be sufficient, no need to start a root login shell.

Comment: I'd probably just write the buffer to a temporary file, then quit and `sudo vi ...`.  It doesn't quite do what you asked, but it avoid having to re-enter the changes you've made.

Comment: I asked the same question about Vim a while ago: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/becoming-root-from-inside-vim

Comment: "sudo su -"?  Read "man sudo", *please*.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the page [Top Ten One-Liners from CommandLineFu Explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/top-ten-one-liners-from-commandlinefu-explained/) is suggested this trick (the #3):

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

this write the current buffer to the `stdin` of the command after the `!`. The `%` symbol is substituted with the current filename.

Comment: Oooh, nice. Will have to remember that.

Comment: A discussion about this very trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work/7078429#7078429

Comment: What will happen if sudo asks you to enter your password? Will this be managed by vi / vim?

Comment: you simply write your password then, and it goes on

Comment: As retrieved from @Fabian's question, the more correct way to do this is `:w !sudo dd of=%` because the way above is an exploit of `tee`, but in practice either works fine.

Comment: omg, 37 up? wow!